# Java - render HTML, JS and CSS and send output html as a string

Tags: java, html, render

im working on a server-side html render.

The case: The user has a simpel page with 3 cells. In each cell he can fill the html, css and JS code. After that, it will be send to the server which render the html and css code considering the javascript code.

My idea was to "simulate" a headless-browser. Till now i just found PhantomJS but i think its not really comfortable.

My result should be only the rendered HTML DOM

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try headless Chrome, this works on all operating systems:

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkgr/headless/README.md

On Linux you have one more option. You can run **any** normal browser with virtual screen buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your response. As far as i see i have to use node.js. Is there a way to stay in the java envoirment without node.js?